# how to configure pylint for greater accuracy

Tags: python, pylint, pylintrc

### Getting false positive from pylint

Consider this code:

```py
previous = None
for word in ['you', 'cannot', 'be', 'serious']:
    if previous is not None:
        print(previous[0], word)
    previous = word
```

Here is the output (no surprises here):

```
$ python3 test.py
y cannot
c be
b serious
```

Checking it using `pylint` gives the following:

```
$ pylint3 test.py
No config file found, using default configuration
************* Module test
C:  1, 0: Missing module docstring (missing-docstring)
C:  1, 0: Constant name "previous" doesn't conform to UPPER_CASE naming style (invalid-name)
E:  4,14: Value 'previous' is unsubscriptable (unsubscriptable-object)

--------------------------------------------------------------------
Your code has been rated at -4.00/10 (previous run: -4.00/10, +0.00)
```

As you can see, `pylint` has complained about the expression `previous[0]` based on the fact that `previous` is initialised to `None`, even though the statement cannot be reached when it has that value.  Additionally, it has complained about the naming style on the basis that `previous` is a constant, despite the assignment on the final line.

**QUESTION:** Is there any suitable configuration of pylint that avoids such false positives without introducing equally blatant false negatives, and if so, why is this not the default?

### Attempted solution: disable test (leads to false negative)

I am able for example to suppress the `unsubscriptable-object` warning entirely, by creating a `$HOME/.pylintrc` containing the output of `pylint3 --generate-rcfile`, and editing it to add `unsubscriptable-object` to the list of disabled tests (see under `disable=` in section `[MESSAGES CONTROL]`).

However, if I simply disable the test in this way, and then validate the following code:

```py
"false negative"  # silence docstring warning (fair enough)

print(None[0])  # this line will fail
```

it tells me:

```
$ pylint3 test2.py
Using config file /home/<myuser>/.pylintrc

--------------------------------------------------------------------
Your code has been rated at 10.00/10 (previous run: 10.00/10, +0.00)
```

So just disabling the test is not really the answer.

### Version and platform info

Version info:

```
$ pylint3 --version
Using config file /home/<myuser>/.pylintrc
pylint3 1.8.3, 
astroid 1.6.0
Python 3.6.9 (default, Apr 18 2020, 01:56:04) 
[GCC 8.4.0]
```

Platform: `Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS`

Comment: Are you using the latest version of pylint?  In my experience the unsubscriptable-object error false positive doesn't occur with their newer versions.  It seems that they regularly improve their type interference logic.  The invalid-name error is not IMHO a false positive.  You select UPPER_CASE_NAMING style for globals in the config file, and "previous" is in fact a global.  So pylint is doing what it's supposed to. 
You can always use a #pylint disable=xxx to suppress an xxx error on a single line.

Comment: @PaulCornelius Tried with 2.5.3 (the latest) and getting essentially the same. Regarding the upper case, the error message refers to a "Constant". It is not a constant.

Comment: Potentially relevant: [pylint issue #3328](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/3328), as well as the [issues labeled `topic-control-flow`](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/labels/topic-control-flow). I assume a type hint would have helped but it doesn't seem to be the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pylint is a static type checker and has all the limitations of that type of utility.  It doesn't read your mind, it only reads your code.  Its purpose is to tell you about suspicious-looking code, and sometimes you have to tell it to ignore certain things because you actually want to write the program that way.

If you expect Pylint to be a flawless code-Nazi that identifies your every mistake, never gets carried away and never misses anything, you will be disappointed.  If you think of it as a friendly observer who can catch some of your errors before you run your program, it is quite powerful.  I consider it an essential tool, as long as you don't ask too much of it.

You say that `previous` is not a constant but that is not how Pylint uses the term.  You declare `previous` at the outermost indentation level of the module and it is therefore a global; Pylint considers the only valid use of globals is as constants.  Hence the error.

To get pylint to accept any format for constants, use this line in the resource configuration file:

```
const-rgx=[A-Za-z0-9_]{1,30}$
```

That's what I have done since I found the default setting, which is

```
const-naming-style=UPPER_CASE
```

to be too restrictive.

The RC file is important, IMO.  It allows you a lot of control over what Pylint does.  If your RC file is named pylint.rc you invoke pylint with the flag `--rcfile=pylint.rc`.  You may have to provide a full path name depending on how your environment is set up.

With the configuration described, Pylint accepts this code without complaint:

```
previous = ''
for word in ['you', 'cannot', 'be', 'serious']:
    if previous:
        print(previous[0], word)
    previous = word
```

It's the same logic, but is easier to understand because it makes clear that previous is a string.  So Pylint has indeed helped you to write more readable code.

It is also sometimes necessary to tell Pylint to stop complaining about a particular line.  In your example, if you really want to initialize previous to None, all you have to do is add an inline pragma, like this:

```
previous = None
for word in ['you', 'cannot', 'be', 'serious']:
    if previous is not None:
        print(previous[0], word)   # pylint: disable=unsubscriptable-object
    previous = word
```

This is a better solution that the one you tried because it defeats the error in one line only, and other occurrences of the same error will get flagged.

Comment: Thank you for a very full reply.